# How to let Guest Users comment on a platform when there is a belong_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails 6 implementing a blog and I want to let users comment on the post even if they are not users in the platform.

I'm not sure how to do this, because currently I'm creating the comment like this

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(
      guest_user: params[:guest_user],
      post_id: params[:post_id],
      user_id: current_user.id,
    )
   ...

  end
```

And Comments `belong_to` User.

I have created a `GuestUser` model to use it as a placeholder but I'm not sure what to do with the id

```
class GuestUser < User
  attr_accessor :name, :first_name, :last_name, :email
end
```

What do you think is the best approach for this?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record?view=asciicast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different ways I believe you could do it, here's one possibly way. Let's say your comment form looked something like this (lots of assumptions given the below, but it should be not too bad to modify this to your needs):

```
= simple_form_for :comment do |f|
  = f.input :comment_body # Not sure what your comment model looks like here, just a guess
  - unless current_user.present? # Don't show the GuestUser fields unless no current_user, will also validate this on the backend
    = f.input :first_name
    = f.input :last_name
    = f.input :email
  # ...
```

In your controller, you could then do something like:

```rb
  def create
    user = current_user || GuestUser.create(guest_params) # Take the current logged in user, or generate a new GuestUser
    redirect_to(#bad_user_path, notice: 'User invalid') unless user.valid? # Mostly a check on GuestUser here

    @comment = user.comments.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save!
      redirect_to (#wherever), notice: 'Saved comment!'
    else
      redirect_to (#wherever), notice: 'Comment invalid'
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_body)
  end
  
  def guest_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
  end
end
```

Again there'd be a few assumptions here, like that your `Comment` model held some `attr_accessor`s for `:first_name, :last_name, :email`, just so you could use `f.input` in the simple form vs `f.text_field`, but that would be one way.

Comment: Another way you could do this would be with a join model -- imagine a model called `UserComments` -- it could have the fields `user_id`, `comment_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` attributes. When building a new  `Comment`, you could `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_comments`, and then if there is a `current_user` just set the `user_id` on that `user_comment` model, and if not set the other attributes (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email` attributes) instead. A guest would then be a comment that had a `user_comment` with no connected `user_id`.